# Why is a magnetic encoder required to detect orientation of BLDC motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, electromagnetic

In the well known “Smart Knob” project: https://github.com/scottbez1/smartknob an magnetic encoder is used directly below the brushless gimbal motor to detect the orientation of the motor. But why is this necessary if the motor has built in Hall effect (or similar) sensors that already determine the orientation in order to spin the motor?

https://www.aspina-group.com/en/learning-zone/columns/what-is/002/

Could you not simply use the values from those sensors to detect and orient the motor as needed?

Comment: the hall effect sensors in the motor get activated multiple times per revolution